# Как из даты получить название месяца в родительном падеже?

Tags: javascript

Из строки вида "21.12.2017" как получить 21 декабря
То есть из числа получить название месяца в родительном падеже
Без использования библиотек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let inpEl = document.getElementById('test'), 
    wYearEl = document.getElementById('year'); 

inpEl.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    this.value = getFullDateStr(this.value, wYearEl.checked) || ''; 
  }
}); 
inpEl.value = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU'); 

function getFullDateStr(dateStr, inclYear = true) {
  const MONTHS = ['января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'];
  let dc = dateStr.match(/(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{4})/);
  if (dc) {
    dc.splice(0, 1);
    dc[0] = +dc[0]; 
    dc[1] = MONTHS[+dc[1] - 1];
    return inclYear ? dc.join(' ') + ' г.' : `${dc[0]} ${dc[1]}`;
  }
}
```

```html
Введите дату в формате [<b>d</b>]<b>d</b>_[<b>m</b>]<b>m</b>_<b>yyyy</b> (где "_" - любой символ),<br>а затем нажмите Enter:<br>
<input id="test" type="text">
<label><input id="year" type="checkbox" checked="">результат с указанием года</label>
```

Доп. информация: выносить массив в глобальную область [не обязательно (тест на jsPerf)](https://jsperf.com/const-array-def-local-vs-global).

Comment: а если 01 - дата, то длжно быть 1 декабря например

Comment: @werty, точно, я забыл об этом. Теперь все ок :) Ну и инпут добавил, для проверки на месте... (если ввод не соответствует формату - значение инпута очищается).